# Fire analytics.js when ASPX form submits

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-analytics

I'm not really familiar with the backend of a site i'm working on, or the technology.

All the pages are .aspx and of course there are aspx.cs files as well.

I have a contact page with a button as so:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit Request" 
onclick="cmdSubmit_Click" />
```

on the aspx.cs file it does some form validations then emails the data to the site owner, and displays an error if there was a problem.

I want to fire a Google Analytics event when this is submitted.  I would accept it firing on button click also.

Comment: Have you checked Event tracking in Google Analytics? You could record custom events such as submitting the contact form. You can read more about that here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide